# DocuSign Connect trigger for Draft Envelopes

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We are exploring options to trigger a DocuSign Connect webhook on envelopes saved as drafts in DocuSign. I don't see that as a Trigger Event option.  Is this possible somehow?  We are trying to leverage using LaserPro to send the documents to DocuSign saved as drafts, then trigger the webhook while still in the Draft status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature DocuSign currently has.

The only event/trigger you can get is when a draft is discarded (Deleted).

Please go to http://feedback.docusign.com/ and make a request for this feature to be added later.